# How to create batch file noting windows version then use xml file to import task

Tags: batch-file, cmd, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

I am looking for a way to have a batch file import a scheduled task called Task Kill.
I am running into an issue with different operating systems and need to have multiple scheduled task xml files, one for Windows 7 and another for Windows 10.
I am looking to have a batch file that can see if it is Windows 7 or Windows 10 and then use the appropriate XML file.

I did not attempt anything as I am not sure how to make this look at the operating system type

```
schtasks /create /tn "Task Kill This Server" /XML "%~dp0Task Kill.xml"
```

Here is the XML File being used

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Task xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task" version="1.4">
    <RegistrationInfo>
        <Date>2019-06-06T09:12:27.4239747</Date>
        <Author>Support</Author>
        <URI>\Task Kill</URI>
    </RegistrationInfo>
    <Triggers>
        <CalendarTrigger>
            <StartBoundary>2019-06-06T06:00:00</StartBoundary>
            <Enabled>true</Enabled>
            <ScheduleByDay>
                <DaysInterval>1</DaysInterval>
            </ScheduleByDay>
        </CalendarTrigger>
    </Triggers>
    <Principals>
        <Principal id="Author">
            <UserId>S-1-5-18</UserId>
            <RunLevel>HighestAvailable</RunLevel>
        </Principal>
    </Principals>
    <Settings>
        <MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
        <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>false</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
        <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>false</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
        <AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
        <StartWhenAvailable>false</StartWhenAvailable>
        <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
        <IdleSettings>
            <StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>
            <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
        </IdleSettings>
        <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
        <Enabled>true</Enabled>
        <Hidden>false</Hidden>
        <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
        <DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession>false</DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession>
        <UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>true</UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>
        <WakeToRun>true</WakeToRun>
        <ExecutionTimeLimit>PT1H</ExecutionTimeLimit>
        <Priority>7</Priority>
    </Settings>
    <Actions Context="Author">
        <Exec>
            <Command>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Company\Program\KillWebcat.bat"</Command>
        </Exec>
    </Actions>
</Task>
```

When importing this file it is only working on Windows 10, not Windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will using the `VER` command provide what is needed?

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%v IN ('VER') DO ( SET "VERSION=%%~v" )
ECHO %VERSION%
```

It would be better if a single XML file could be used.

Comment: How can a single XML be used for each operating system? That is my obstacle.

Comment: I have never done this before. I would start by exporting the same task to an XML file  from both Windows 10 and Windows 7. Then, I would compare the two to identify differences. Have you tried to import the Windows 7 exported file on Windows 10 to see if it will accept it?

Answer (score 0):

The following is a batch file which will determine if your Opertaing System is Windows 7 or Windows 10. Just replace the `Echo` message with the commands you need.

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "EOL=O Delims=" %%A In (
    '"WMIc OS Get OSArchitecture,ProductType,Version 2>Nul"'
) Do For /F "Tokens=1,3-5 Delims=-. " %%B In ("%%A"
) Do If %%C Equ 1 Call :v%%D%%Ex%%B 2>Nul
Pause
Exit/B

:v61x32
Echo Windows 7 x86 Commands
GoTo :EOF

:v61x64
Echo Windows 7 x64 Commands
GoTo :EOF

:v100x32
Echo Windows 10 x86 Commands
GoTo :EOF

:v100x64
Echo Windows 10 x64 Commands
GoTo :EOF
```

If the 'bitness' of the Operating System doesn't matter, then you could use this instead:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "EOL=O Delims=" %%A In (
    '"WMIc OS Get OSArchitecture,ProductType,Version 2>Nul"'
) Do For /F "Tokens=1,3-5 Delims=-. " %%B In ("%%A"
) Do If %%C Equ 1 Call :v%%D%%Ex%%B 2>Nul
Pause
Exit/B

:v61x32
:v61x64
Echo Windows 7 Commands
GoTo :EOF

:v100x32
:v100x64
Echo Windows 10 Commands
GoTo :EOF
```

*Please note in both cases, that the `Pause` command is only included in order for you to read the `Echo` messages, you may find that removing those when replacing the `Echo`es with your own commands is better for your purposes.*